Why is assuming the constancy of $c$ insufficient for obtaining the Lorentz transformations?
I recently started reading A. O. Barut's Electrodynamics and Classical Theory of Fields and Particles. In the first chapter, Barut derives an equation that is saidd to uniquely determine the Lorentz transformations. He achieved this by assuming the constancy of the speed of light and considering light propagating as a spherical wave. The argument goes roughly as follows:

The equation of the wavefront for light propagating as a spherical
wave is given by:
$$c^2t^2 - x_1^2 - x_2^2-x_3^2=0$$
The constancy of the speed of light $c$ implies now that in any other
inertial frame to be defined, which at $t=0$ coincides with the first,
the equation of the wavefront is given by:
$$c^2t'^2 - x_1'^2 - x_2'^2-x_3'^2=0$$
This is only possible if $t' \neq t$, because $x_i' \neq x_i$. Observe
also that, by dimensional analysis, if $c^2t^2 - x_1^2 -x_2^2-x_3^2=a$, then $a$ has units of distance squared. Thus, the
Lorentz transformation must be such that:
$$c^2t^2 - x_1^2 - x_2^2-x_3^2=a\qquad \implies \qquad c^2t'^2 - x_1'^2 - x_2'^2-x_3'^2=a$$
The Lorentz transformations are then uniquely determined by the equation:
$$c^2t^2 - x_1^2 - x_2^2-x_3^2= c^2t'^2 -x_1'^2 - x_2'^2-x_3'^2=a$$

Barut claims that, from an "experimental standpoint", the constancy of the speed of light is insufficient to obtain this equation. As per Barut, two additional experiments are needed— one being the demonstration of the independence of the transit time of light along a closed path from the velocity of the Earth.
My questions are twofold:

Why is it that this particular argument that relies on more than the constancy and invariance of the speed of light? It is not obvious where in the argument we make any further assumptions, implicit or explicit.
If we assume the constancy of $c$ in all frames, does that not imply the independence of the transit time of light along a closed path from the velocity of the Earth?


See: Rothenstein, Bernhard, and George Eckstein. "Lorentz transformations directly from the speed of light." American Journal of Physics 63.12 (1995): 1150-1150, wherein the only assumption is that $c$ is invariant and constant.

There are a number of ways that the additional information needed to derive the $O(3,1)$ Lorentz transformations can be supplied.  The simplest version is to take as additional postulates that space is homogeneous and isotropic for all observers.  These are often glossed over as so obvious that they need not be stated as assumptions.  Problem 11.1 of Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics shows what you can derive the Lorentz boosts starting from these conditions and the constancy of $c$.

This answer elaborates on the answer by contributor Buzz.
The assumptions of homogeneity and isotropy of space are far reaching assumptions.
There is a long tradition of putting emphasis on homogeneity and isotropy of space, and the principle of relativity of inertial motion, rather than on invariance of the speed of light.
There is the discussion by Palash B. Pal titled: Nothing but relativity
Palash B Pal shows that assuming homogeneity and isotropy of space, plus assumption of relativity of inertial motion, is already enough to narrow down the possibilities to just two options: Galilean transformations, and Lorentz transformation. The final say is then to be made on the basis of experimental evidence.

While it is the case that historically it was electromagnetism that provided the clues towards recognition of the Lorentz transformations, the validity/significance of the Lorentz transformations extends beyond electromagnetism.
If the Minkowski metric is granted as axiom then the invariance of the speed of light follows as a theorem.
I prefer to think of the transition to relativistic mechanics as a transition from assuming the euclidean metric to assuming the Minkowski metric.
That said: it would be unreasonable to expect that around 1905 physicists should already have been thinking in terms of metric of spacetime. It was the introduction of relativistic physics that made it possible to recognize the concept of Minkowski metric. So I understand why in 1905 the invariance of the speed of light was used. The introduction of the concept of metric of spacetime by Hermann Minkowski was, in my opinion, a significant advancement.
